# Convert Json Dictionary Objects to Python dicitonary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a Json file with dictionary like objects

```
{"d1a": 91, "d1b": 2, "d1c": 1, "d1d": 5, "d1e": 7, "d1f": 77, "d1e": 999}
{"d2a": 1, "d2b": 2, "d2c": 3, "d2d": 4, "d2e": 5, "d2f": 6, "d2e": 7}
{"d3a": 1, "d3b": 2, "d3c": 3, "d3d": 4, "d3e": 5, "d3f": 6, "d3e": 7}
```

I want to convert this into a python dictionary with the same format

```
with open(myfile.json, 'r') as myfile:
# not sure how the conversion will start
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is how the file contents looks as is, it is not a valid JSON as a whole, but each line is.

You can read the file *line by line* and call `json.loads()`:

```
import json

with open(myfile.json, 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print(json.loads(line))
```

And you can have a list of dictionaries if you would use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
objs = [json.loads(line) for line in myfile]
```

You can also call the `loads()` once if you would surround the contents with `[` and `]` and put commas at the end of each line:

```
with open("test.json") as myfile:
    data = "[" + ",".join(myfile.readlines()) + "]"
    print(json.loads(data))
```

Comment: The objs = [json.loads(line) for line in myfile], seems to return two entries instead of the original 3 in the json file

Comment: Sorry i had, an extra loop in my code which took out a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, you need to

```
import json
```

Then,

```
with open(myfile.json, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Also, you have no included valid JSON. You can wrap what you have in an array to make it parse properly:

```
[
    {"d1a": 91, "d1b": 2, "d1c": 1, "d1d": 5, "d1e": 7, "d1f": 77, "d1e": 999},
    {"d2a": 1, "d2b": 2, "d2c": 3, "d2d": 4, "d2e": 5, "d2f": 6, "d2e": 7},
    {"d3a": 1, "d3b": 2, "d3c": 3, "d3d": 4, "d3e": 5, "d3f": 6, "d3e": 7}
]
```